# Crossfilter.js: Creating Dimensions/Groups With Nested Attributes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nested, crossfilter

I'm working on a visualization utilizing the crossfilter.js library, and I'm a bit confused on how to create some dimensions from nested attributes within my dataset. For instance, each instance of the dataset has multiple dates associated with it, resulting in a data structure that looks like this:

```
[ { name: 'instance_name',
  dates: ['2014-11-11', '2013-07-06', '2011-02-04'],
  category: 'category 1' },
{ name: 'instance_name2',
  dates: ['2012-01-01', '2013-03-07'],
  category: 'category 2' } ]
```

I'd like to be able to create dimensions that will allow for filtering based on, say, the dates and the category and dimensions are a straightforward way to do this with crossfilter. However, I'm not sure how to parse the dates. I've tried first creating a date dimension using something like:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var dateDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.dates; });
```

and then tried to store just the dates as a variable using the `.map()` method like so:

```
var date = dateDim.top(Infinity).map(function(d) { return d.dates; });
```

The above does retrieve just the dates and stores them as a variable, however (a) this is just an array of dates each of which is a string, and (b) this doesn't get me any closer to linking the `dateDim` to other crossfilter dimensions I'd like to create for the visualization. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is be to flatten your structure before loading it in to Crossfilter. So your 1st record will become 3 records (1 for each date) and your 2nd record will become 2 records. You can then parse the dates and treat them as a dimension in Crossfilter without too much trouble. The downside is that counting because a problem, but that is manageable with custom grouping functions.

Comment: What sort of custom grouping function would mitigate the counting problem here?

Comment: A grouping that only counts the first of each unique key (in this case, the 'name' field) that it sees in a group. Reductio's exception aggregation is an example, albeit confusingly named: https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-exception-aggregation

Comment: I think this was just marked as correct, but it's not actually optimal any more :-) In the Crossfilter 1.4.0 alphas, you can use a dimension array to handle this without flattening.